# is it possible to send Get request with ajax to any other domain like other back end Languages

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

What i want to know is, that can i send a get request with ajax for instance to stackoverflow.com with ajax and get the response, like for example:

**Sending a Get request to stackoverflow with Node JS.**

```
const https = require("https");

https.get("https://stackoverflow.com", res => {
    res.on("data", data => {
        console.log(data.toString());
    })
})
```

I got all the Html code in the response.

Now if i try to send the same requests but through AJAX.

```
$.getJSON("https://stackoverflow.com", response => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

I end up with this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://stackoverflow.com/. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

Comment: Short answer: No. You'll be blocked by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) unless the response includes CORS headers - which the vast majority do not.

Comment: you can send GET requests, just can't get the responses unless it is JSONP or CORS enabled or an image, script, or stylesheet with script/image tags.

Comment: Rory McCrossan, can you please explain me further more, i'm still confused that how it's is possible to send the same request with node js.

Comment: It's because Node runs on the server. Client side JS cross domain requests are blocked by the SOP (as linked to above) for security reasons.

Comment: AKA, do you want some random person to access your gmail account, bank, facebook with Ajax requests when you view some random site? No, hence why there is the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: The way I used to go was "making the request from your backend", you can make the call to a script on your server that then makes the GET request to the site, process the received data and return it to you, I used to do it like that a couple years ago with the Instagram API... if you are trying to do it like requesting the site, I believe it won't work either.